# Google storage external authorization

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-oauth

I need to store my service data in Google Storage and let my users download files depending on their (users) access rights.

I've already made service that connects to Google Storage using server-centric mechanism, and transfers them to client-side, but I need client-side to go to Storage and download file without server-side.

I've tried to use temporary links for files, but I can't check, if user downloaded file or not to properly delete temporary link.

I've tried to look for oauth2 support, but it seems Google doesn't support oauth in such way (When my service decides to allow access or no).

The best solution is to generate tokens for users and if Google Storage would call my service before every file download.

How can I achieve that?